# Resize image with PHP to new directory

Tags: php, image, resize

I really don't know what's wrong here and why it isn't recreating the new image to a new directory. Please help! The image isn't being created for some reason. I'm coding everything in Microsoft's WebMatrix.

```
    public static function imgResize($imgdir){
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgdir);

        $ratio = $width/$height;
        $new_height = 90;
        $new_width = round($new_height * $ratio);

        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        $old_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgdir);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        imagejpeg($new_image, "gal/newimages/", 100);
    }
```

Comment: What is it doing ? Is there an error message ? Is the image no the same size ? Be more precise to get help.

Comment: For example, do you have write permissions to the folder newimages?

Comment: You need to learn basic debugging. All of your posted code simply assumes success and procedes blindly. If any of the image*() functions fail, they return boolean false... and you simply ignore that.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to use a Microsoft product.

Comment: I've coded lots of sites fine with Microsoft's WebMatrix on Windows. I get the same results as if I was coding on Ubuntu Linux. All because the product is from Microsoft, doesn't mean it's a failure. Anyways help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagejpeg needs a filename, not a directory. Try:

```
imagejpeg($new_image, "gal/newimages/" . basename($imgdir), 100);
```

also, does the folder exist? If not, you need to create it first.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. Can't believe it was that simple. Back to work :)